# How to limit a chunks function?

Tags: python, batch-processing

I am trying to create a chunks function, the idea is that it repeats certain task for an specific number of elements in a list (denoted by `n`)

An example is if `n=5` then print just the first 5 elements.

Here's my attempt:

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
        

a_random_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        
just_some_chunks = list(chunks(a_random_list, 5))

print(just_some_chunks)
```

Console Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

How could I adjust `chunks()` function in order to retrieve first `n` elements?

Comment: Just use `next(chunks(a_random_list, 5))` if you need only first part. To slice some amount you can use either [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) or simple list comp `[el for _, el in zip(range(n), chunks(a_random_list, 5))]`

Comment: Just slice and return? - `def chunks(lst, n): return lst[:n]`